# Реально ли за год стать Junior Java Developer?

Tags: работа, java

Сейчас я закончил второй курс по программированию. Знания у меня на данный момент не самые лучшие и я просто знаю, что такое программирование, но программировать не умею. Но я себе поставил четкую цель, кем я хочу быть и срок. Я хочу самостоятельно обучиться на junior java developer с уклоном на веб. Срок 1 год. Затем я начну искать себе работу, в первую очередь не ради зарплаты, а ради опыта, переживу, даже если мне ее не будут платить. Я определился с литературой, по которой буду заниматься. Начну я с "Полный справочник по Java. Java SE™ 6 Edition (7-e издание), Хорстман, Корнелл. Java 2 — двух томник".

Я планирую сделать так: прочитать книжку Шилдта, закрепляя каждую главу 5-7 упражнениями из задачника. Я получу базовые навыки по java. Конечно, я не буду иметь огромные знания по алгоритмам и структурам данных, но я буду знать основный синтаксис. За какой-нибудь проект я возьмусь после прочтения Шилдта, когда будут какие-то знания. А то пока браться за какой проект без знаний это не дело. "Брюс Эккель — Философия Java" (читать буду в том порядке, в котором описано). Жду вашей критики, меня интересует реально ли добиться данной цели?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Одного года вам впролне хватит, чтоб стать junior dev. Но и здесь все зависит от вас. Думаю, если у вас есть более опытный друг, то за год под его руководством вы смогли б дотянутся до уровня некоторых (не самых сильных) dev.

Толстые книжки - это круто, но это не даст вам всего того, что нужно на практике. Кроме синтаксиса вам нужно знать много базовых классов, что позволит вам выбирать нужные средства для решения поставленных задач. Кроме этого желательно:

- xml (знать),
- regexp (знать),
- uml (иметь понятие),
- SQL,
- работа средствами jdbc (знать),
- hibernate и ему подобные (иметь понятие),
- mvc фреймворки (типа spring, иметь понятие),
- потоки (знать как отченаш, если вы планируете писать серверную часть),
- паттерны программирования (иметь понятие хотя бы о самых простых, - паттерны создания).

(Список можно продолжить, но пока на ум ничего больше не приходит.)

Стоит первых 3 месяца позаниматся над синтаксисом. Следующих 3 потратить на решение задачок с олимпиад по программированию, повозится с сортировками, что даст вам опыт и понимание некоторых средств языка. Потом можно занятся разучиванием из списка.

Под самый "конец" обучения можно искать предложения трудоустройства для java se, искать web-проэкты на java и знакомится с технологиями требуемыми от, используемыми на.

Answer (score 0):

Реально. И можно даже быстрее. Все зависит от ваших способностей, упорства, количества лени и так далее.

Comment: Согласен полностью, но вот автору вопроса хотел бы посоветовать делать уклон именно в алгоритмы а не в знание синтаксиса

Comment: Верно.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно многое знать, так как некоторая база знаний у данной квалификации должна имется =) 
Успехов.

Answer (score -1):

[Вот](http://javatalks.ru/ftopic19120.php) очень хороший вебинар на эту тему. И все-таки думаю, что года вам не хватит. От juniora требуют не только хорошее знание языка и ООП, но и знание базовых алгоритмов, структур данных, в т.ч. и БД. Нужно знать как со всем этим работать и какие есть подводные камни. Если вы хотите уходить в веб-разработку, то придется ознакомится хотя бы на базовом уровне с J2EE, DI-фреймворками(Spring), ORM(Hibernate), ну и с Mavenом или Ant'ом тоже неплохо опыт иметь. 
Не говоря уже о паттернах и многопоточности, а это тоже иногда требуют у джуниоров.
Удачи, главное не останавливаться!

Comment: Я думаю, что все эти технологии будут плюсом, но никак не обязательными для Джуниора. На то он и Джуниор, чтобы были обобщенные знания по языку, ООП, алгоритмы в голове, но без технологий, которым Фирма сама обучит на реальных проектах.